# Где хранить логин и пароль от бд при разработке?

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-jpa

В общем и в целом пилю какие-то проекты на `Java Spring Framework` в процессе обучения. Для локальной разработки годится хранить данные для подключения к бд в `application.properties`.

Но услышал от коллеги который уже устроился и довольно долго работает, что это одна из самых грубых ошибок. Ну это как бы понятно. НО
Собственно вопрос где хранить те же настройки с логинами паролями?

Каким образом я могу их подключить если у меня грубо говоря есть сервер c доступом по `ssh` и приложение упакованное в `jar/war`?

Коллега говорит что при деплое их передают как аргументы командной строки.
Какие вообще есть варианты или это единственный верный?

Comment: Как аргументы командной строки — тоже одна из самых грубых ошибок, потому что эти самые аргументы отлично видны в списке процессов всем пользователям. Или в файле (таком, который не внутри jar и доступа к которому нет ни у кого кроме пользователя приложения), или в переменных окружения (которые тоже посторонним не видны)

Comment: Если используются контейнеры - то собственно в них, есть специальные переменные. Если сервер приложений, то можно вынести в файл настроек, который хранится на сервере и при старте вы его читаете. Можно как аргугементы (правда такое не встречал). Сейчас чаще, конечно, юзают кубер и секьюрити там. Еще вариант использовать Vault